# Undefined reference to 'snapend'

Tags: c, compiler-construction, reference, cross-compiling

While I was trying to make an `LLDP` functionality implemented in my project with my current knowledge of C, I ran in to this problem. The compile gives out an error stating,

`/home/tiara/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:212: undefined reference to`snapend'`

The code segment that generate this is,

```
voidlldp_print(const u_char *p, u_int len)
{
    u_int16_t tlv;
    u_int8_t *ptr = (u_int8_t *)p, v = 0;
    int n, type, vlen, alen;

    printf("LLDP");

#define _ptrinc(_v) ptr += (_v); vlen -= (_v);

    for (n = 0; n < len;) {
        TCHECK2(*ptr, sizeof(tlv)); //HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS TO
```

Your advice on how to correct this error would be very much appreciated as I was trying to solve this for days and had no luck.

Thanks again :)

**FYI**

Following are the `libraries` that I have included in the code

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <net/if.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/in_systm.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "addrtoname.h"
#include "extract.h"
#include "interface.h"
#include "afnum.h"
```

**EDIT**

`TECHECK2` is defined in `interface.h` header file located here http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/src/usr.sbin/tcpdump/interface.h

```
/*  $OpenBSD: interface.h,v 1.62 2014/01/11 04:35:52 lteo Exp $ */

/*
 * Copyright (c) 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997
 *  The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that: (1) source code distributions
 * retain the above copyright notice and this paragraph in its entirety, (2)
 * distributions including binary code include the above copyright notice and
 * this paragraph in its entirety in the documentation or other materials
 * provided with the distribution, and (3) all advertising materials mentioning
 * features or use of this software display the following acknowledgement:
 * ``This product includes software developed by the University of California,
 * Lawrence Berkeley Laboratory and its contributors.'' Neither the name of
 * the University nor the names of its contributors may be used to endorse
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior
 * written permission.
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED ``AS IS'' AND WITHOUT ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, WITHOUT LIMITATION, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 *
 * @(#) $Id: interface.h,v 1.62 2014/01/11 04:35:52 lteo Exp $ (LBL)
 */

#ifndef tcpdump_interface_h
#define tcpdump_interface_h

#include "gnuc.h"
#ifdef HAVE_OS_PROTO_H
#include "os-proto.h"
#endif

struct tok {
    int v;          /* value */
    char *s;        /* string */
};

extern int aflag;       /* translate network and broadcast addresses */
extern int dflag;       /* print filter code */
extern int eflag;       /* print ethernet header */
extern int fflag;       /* don't translate "foreign" IP address */
extern int Iflag;       /* include interface in output */
extern int nflag;       /* leave addresses as numbers */
extern int Nflag;       /* remove domains from printed host names */
extern int oflag;       /* OS fingerprint */
extern int qflag;       /* quick (shorter) output */
extern int Sflag;       /* print raw TCP sequence numbers */
extern int tflag;       /* print packet arrival time */
extern int vflag;       /* verbose */
extern int xflag;       /* print packet in hex */
extern int Xflag;       /* print packet in hex/ascii */

extern int packettype;      /* as specified by -T */
extern char *device;        /* as specified by -i  */
#define PT_VAT      1   /* Visual Audio Tool */
#define PT_WB       2   /* distributed White Board */
#define PT_RPC      3   /* Remote Procedure Call */
#define PT_RTP      4   /* Real-Time Applications protocol */
#define PT_RTCP     5   /* Real-Time Applications control protocol */
#define PT_CNFP     6   /* Cisco NetFlow protocol */
#define PT_VRRP     7   /* Virtual Router Redundancy protocol */
#define PT_TCP      8   /* TCP */

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(b):(a))
#endif
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) ((b)>(a)?(b):(a))
#endif

/*
 * The default snapshot length.  This value allows most printers to print
 * useful information while keeping the amount of unwanted data down.
 * In particular, it allows ethernet, tcp/ip headers, and a small amount
 * of data, or to capture IPv6 and TCP headers after pflog encapsulation.
 */
#define DEFAULT_SNAPLEN 116
#define IEEE802_11_SNAPLEN (DEFAULT_SNAPLEN + 30)
#define IEEE802_11_RADIO_SNAPLEN (IEEE802_11_SNAPLEN + 64)

#ifndef BIG_ENDIAN
#define BIG_ENDIAN 4321
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN 1234
#endif

#ifdef ETHER_HEADER_HAS_EA
#define ESRC(ep) ((ep)->ether_shost.ether_addr_octet)
#define EDST(ep) ((ep)->ether_dhost.ether_addr_octet)
#else
#define ESRC(ep) ((ep)->ether_shost)
#define EDST(ep) ((ep)->ether_dhost)
#endif

#ifdef ETHER_ARP_HAS_X
#define SHA(ap) ((ap)->arp_xsha)
#define THA(ap) ((ap)->arp_xtha)
#define SPA(ap) ((ap)->arp_xspa)
#define TPA(ap) ((ap)->arp_xtpa)
#else
#ifdef ETHER_ARP_HAS_EA
#define SHA(ap) ((ap)->arp_sha.ether_addr_octet)
#define THA(ap) ((ap)->arp_tha.ether_addr_octet)
#else
#define SHA(ap) ((ap)->arp_sha)
#define THA(ap) ((ap)->arp_tha)
#endif
#define SPA(ap) ((ap)->arp_spa)
#define TPA(ap) ((ap)->arp_tpa)
#endif

#ifndef NTOHL
#define NTOHL(x)    (x) = ntohl(x)
#define NTOHS(x)    (x) = ntohs(x)
#define HTONL(x)    (x) = htonl(x)
#define HTONS(x)    (x) = htons(x)
#endif
#endif

extern char *program_name;  /* used to generate self-identifying messages */

extern int32_t thiszone;    /* seconds offset from gmt to local time */

extern int snaplen;
/* global pointers to beginning and end of current packet (during printing) */
extern const u_char *packetp;
extern const u_char *snapend;

/*
 * True if  "l" bytes of "var" were captured.
 *
 * The "snapend - (l) <= snapend" checks to make sure "l" isn't so large
 * that "snapend - (l)" underflows.
 *
 * The check is for <= rather than < because "l" might be 0.
 */
#define TTEST2(var, l) (snapend - (l) <= snapend && \
            (const u_char *)&(var) <= snapend - (l))

/* True if "var" was captured */
#define TTEST(var) TTEST2(var, sizeof(var))

/* Bail if "l" bytes of "var" were not captured */
#define TCHECK2(var, l) if (!TTEST2(var, l)) goto trunc

/* Bail if "var" was not captured */
#define TCHECK(var) TCHECK2(var, sizeof(var))

struct timeval;
struct bpf_timeval;

extern void ts_print(const struct bpf_timeval *);

extern int fn_print(const u_char *, const u_char *);
extern int fn_printn(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void relts_print(int);
extern const char *tok2str(const struct tok *, const char *, int);
extern char *dnaddr_string(u_short);
extern void safeputs(const char *);
extern void safeputchar(int);
extern void printb(char *, unsigned short, char *);

extern void wrapup(int);

extern __dead void error(const char *, ...)
    __attribute__((__format__ (printf, 1, 2)));
extern void warning(const char *, ...)
    __attribute__ ((__format__ (printf, 1, 2)));

extern char *read_infile(char *);
extern char *copy_argv(char * const *);

extern char *isonsap_string(const u_char *);
extern char *llcsap_string(u_char);
extern char *protoid_string(const u_char *);
extern char *dnname_string(u_short);
extern char *dnnum_string(u_short);

/* The printer routines. */

struct pcap_pkthdr;

extern int ether_encap_print(u_short, const u_char *, u_int, u_int);
extern int llc_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int, const u_char *,
    const u_char *);
extern int pppoe_if_print(u_short, const u_char *, u_int, u_int);
extern void aarp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void arp_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int);
extern void atalk_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void atalk_print_llap(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void atm_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void bootp_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_short, u_short);
extern void bgp_print(const u_char *, int);
extern void decnet_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int);
extern void default_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void default_print_unaligned(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void dvmrp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void egp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void enc_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void pflog_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void pflog_old_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void pfsync_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void pfsync_ip_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ether_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void fddi_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void ppp_ether_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void gre_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void icmp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ieee802_11_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void ieee802_11_radio_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void iapp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void igrp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ip_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void ipx_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void isoclns_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int, const u_char *,
    const u_char *);
extern void krb_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void netbeui_print(u_short, const u_char *, const u_char *);
extern void ipx_netbios_print(const u_char *, const u_char *);
extern void nbt_tcp_print(const u_char *, int);
extern void nbt_udp137_print(const u_char *data, int);
extern void nbt_udp138_print(const u_char *data, int);
extern char *smb_errstr(int, int);
extern void print_data(const unsigned char *, int);
extern void l2tp_print(const u_char *dat, u_int length);
extern void vrrp_print(const u_char *bp, u_int len, int ttl);
extern void carp_print(const u_char *bp, u_int len, int ttl);
extern void hsrp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void vqp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void nfsreply_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void nfsreq_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ns_print(const u_char *, u_int, int);
extern void ntp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void loop_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void null_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void ospf_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void mobile_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void pim_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void ppp_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void ppp_hdlc_print(const u_char *, int);
extern void raw_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void rip_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void sl_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);
extern void sl_bsdos_if_print(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *,
    const u_char *);
extern void snmp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void sunrpcrequest_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void cnfp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void tcp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void tftp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void timed_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void udp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void wb_print(const void *, u_int);
extern void ike_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void udpencap_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ah_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void esp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void cdp_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int, const u_char *,
    const u_char *);
extern void stp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void radius_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void lwres_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void ether_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void etherip_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ipcomp_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void mpls_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void lldp_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void slow_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void gtp_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_short, u_short);

#ifdef INET6
extern void ip6_print(const u_char *, int);
extern void ip6_opt_print(const u_char *, int);
extern int hbhopt_print(const u_char *);
extern int dstopt_print(const u_char *);
extern int frag6_print(const u_char *, const u_char *);
extern void icmp6_print(const u_char *, u_int, const u_char *);
extern void ripng_print(const u_char *, int);
extern int rt6_print(const u_char *, const u_char *);
extern void ospf6_print(const u_char *, u_int);
extern void dhcp6_print(const u_char *, u_int, u_short, u_short);
#endif /*INET6*/

extern u_short in_cksum(const u_short *addr, register int len, int csum);
```

**EDIT 2**

Thaks to the comments I wa able to narrow down the question. and what I need to know is, why it is generating the error `Undefined reference to snapped` when

`TCHECK2(*ptr, sizeof(tlv));`

clearly passes two values to the `TCHECK2` method

```
extern const u_char *snapend;

/*
 * True if  "l" bytes of "var" were captured.
 *
 * The "snapend - (l) <= snapend" checks to make sure "l" isn't so large
 * that "snapend - (l)" underflows.
 *
 * The check is for <= rather than < because "l" might be 0.
 */
#define TTEST2(var, l) (snapend - (l) <= snapend && \
            (const u_char *)&(var) <= snapend - (l))

/* True if "var" was captured */
#define TTEST(var) TTEST2(var, sizeof(var))

/* Bail if "l" bytes of "var" were not captured */
#define TCHECK2(var, l) if (!TTEST2(var, l)) goto trunc

/* Bail if "var" was not captured */
#define TCHECK(var) TCHECK2(var, sizeof(var))
```

any advice would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: And how are we supposed to know what `TCHECK2()` does? Is it your macro? Then you should include the definition. If it isn't your, why do you use it?

Comment: @alk i provided the header file where it defines the `TCHECK2` amd thank you for the reply

Comment: @unwind Thank you for the pointer. I provided the code which defines the `TCHECK2` in the question :)

Comment: So now as you moved and digged this out you could solve this issues yourself, can't you?

Comment: Then you'll have to find where `snapend` is defined in the tcpdump code.  (Why do you include an arbitrary header file from the tcpdump code ?)

Comment: @alk The thing that puzzles me is the `snapend` reference error :(

Comment: @nos okey sir, will try to find that and post back :) thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

`snapend` is declared in `interface.h`. What you also need is a definition of `snapend`. So either put (copied from interface.h)

```
const u_char *snapend;
```

into your project or link against a lib that contains the variable snapend (I don't know if you are just taking the header files from tcpdump or also using the .o files or libraries from tcpdump).

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir, I will check and post back :)

Comment: Hi, I added the definition `const u_char *snapend;` under the definition `extern const u_char *snapend;` and it did build successfully. But will this bring up issues when the program is actually running?

Comment: The declaration is in a header file; declarations can be included and repeated in multiple source files and still refer to the same variable. The definition can not be included multiple times. If snapend is not defined in a library, then define it once only, typically in the file with main().